# JWT generate token with algorithm ES256

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

I am trying to generate an accessToken with algorithm ES256 and I use the following very very simple code:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const accessToken = jwt.sign(
  { name: 'John' },
  'testsecret',
  { expiresIn: '24h' },
  { algorithm: 'ES256' }
)

console.log(accessToken)
```

And I got a token as below:

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiIsImlhdCI6MTYxNDY4MzUxNCwiZXhwIjoxNjE0NzY5OTE0fQ.Q9quAufyTQvPvKrTUXzRDUo-o0M4yXSXjqU4vZ9nvvA

I tried pasting this to jwt.io and it seems that it is a HS256 token instead of ES256, did I miss anything?

There is something that I did not do correctly. You can always paste the above code to nodejs and you will see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to combine the `expiresIn` and `algorithm` arguments - the module takes a single options object:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const privatekey = `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEICXoLhGdD6jzX5ePTY9O9YBgv0ZZ6oBWDRsjKaeASXp6oAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAELCnuRSU9Vf+bx65i3Vbibj123RQFrIEaXuMuXunzPXGURKge07fy
FoiMucdGZ2MZGsm37JdlnVGd5yU1h4D4Rg==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----`

const payload = {"id":1}

const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, privatekey, {
  expiresIn: "24h",
  algorithm: "ES256",
});
```

Comment: @jps you got ES256?

Comment: yes! I used exactly that code  from the answer. Of course you need a ES256 key for it. So again, what error do you get? I see in the last edit of your question you replaced the private key with a simple string. That can't work. Before you loaded a key from a file.

Comment: there is no error message, may I know how you have generated the private key? I use something like "testsecret" like the code above

Comment: see my comment above, you need a proper key and seems you loaded one before. You can generate keys on https://8gwifi.org/jwsgen.jsp

Comment: openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -noout -out private.pem.  this is now I have generated the key

Comment: I edited the answer to show a complete example. Please try that, it should work for you.

Comment: regarding your openssl command, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349140/invalid-jwt-signature-with-es256/66371706#comment117300743_66349140). You need secp256r1.